# Can Visitor Design Pattern and Observer Design Pattern be combined?

Tags: java, user-interface, design-patterns, observer-pattern, visitor-pattern

Let me say I have a simple Java program, which reads some files and displays some data.

I am confused, I think a pattern should be applied but I can't decide which one to implement.

Here is the **scenario**:

Whenever I choose a directory I want my program to **display** the directory name, all the files list and other data (like file sizes, file extensions etc.) Whenever I click a filename I want my program to display its' path, preview it if it is an image file and some other stuff.

The program would keep keep the data in a **dataHolder** class: File selectedDirectory, List filesInthatDirectory, File selectedFile, JSONObject fileData etc...

That program would have many **GUI objects** for display; textfields, panels, labels, lists.

Classic old approach would be writing all the code in a single method *press a button -> inside the actionListener *get files from the disk, *read their names and other stuff, *fill the GUI objects with data. This is kinda bad.

So I decided to use a **design pattern**. Then whenever I click this button and read from the disk, I would only **update** the dataHolder class (setSelectedDirectory, setFileData, fillCurrentFilesList.. methods like these) And these update operations would **trigger** classes which will do the needed GUI updates.

But I stayed between two approaches;

-With **Observer pattern**, I create some observers, for example when dataHolder's fileData (JSON) object is updated I would notify related textFields, then they will display the proper data.

-But with **Visitor pattern**, a visitor class will handle different objects, it would run different codes for different GUI classes. JList will try to display a List or some textFields will try to parse a JSONObject and display only the related String. But I do not need much different functions, I mean I only want the GUI objects to display some data, my only visitor class would be a DisplayVisitor which will expect the GUI display object's only job - display the data. If I needed doSomethingVisitor, doAnotherThingVisitor, doAmazingThingVisitor... classes that approach would be nice but I don't need another functions.

Do both approaches do the trick? I just can't get the difference for this scenario. Both of them offer a solution, Observer is more simple but does it offer handling different GUI classes like filling a JList with Arraylist or making a JLabel displaying an jpeg File?

Or Can I combine these patterns? Thanks for reading.

Comment: "_I think a pattern should be applied..._" Why? Patterns are never required. "_I am confused,_" That's a good reason to forget about patterns and solve the problem in the simplest possible way. Consider refactoring to patterns after the code is working. It sounds like patterns are a problem rather than a solution right now.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the Observer pattern is more suitable for your case. The Visitor pattern is for scenarios when you want to add functionality to some objects that you can't/don't want to modify.